# How to create a Discord Cross server relay bot in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been working on a new Discord Bot which would be able to relay an announcement from the origin server to all other servers the bot is in. I am very new to programming so is there any hope for my idea. I'll send my current code right now.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new discord.Client();

const token = '<token>';

const PREFIX = '&';

const server;
const DChannel;

bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Milsim Network Online');

    server = bot.guilds.get(719415100221554688);
    DChannel = server.channels.get(719424622633680906);
    console.log('--------------------\n\n\nREADY: '+ new Date() +'\n\n\n--------------------');
})

bot.on('message', message=> {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" "); // Single Argument Commands //

    switch(args[0]) {
        case 'ping': 
            message.channel.send('pong!');
        break;
        case 'UMA':
            message.channel.send('website link here');
        break;
        case 'info':
            message.channel.send('Please select: **PMC**, **MILSIM**, or **UMA** to learn more about them');
        break;
    }

    if (message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'dm' || message.channel.type.toLowerCase() == 'group') {
            var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
            .setDescription(message.content)
            .setTimestamp(new Date())
            .setColor('#C735D4');
            DChannel.send(embed);
        }
})

bot.login (token);
```

I understand it may seem very disorganized and messy and I apologize for that.

Comment: I hope that's not your actual token. If it is, you will need to regenerate it asap. I edited it out of your question, just in case, but... anyone with enough reputation can still see it.

Comment: Oh dont worry, that was my old token

Comment: Was worth checking. You wouldn't believe the number or *real* tokens I've seen. Especially on cloud computing storage & databases.

Comment: Oh that must hurt them a lot when they realize what they did. But thanks anyways for removing the old token. That would've gone south fast if I put in the real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step in the desired direction. My example gets the rest of the message content (not including the command) and sends it to the first channel of every guild the client is in. Note that 'first' channel means the one lowest on the channel list.

```
let announcement = args.slice(1).join(' ');
bot.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
  let channel = guild.channels.cache.first();
  channel.send(announcement);
});
```

It does appear that you're not using discord.js v12, so the above code will only work if you remove all instances of `cache`, e.g `bot.guilds.cache.forEach()` --> `bot.guilds.forEach()`

Comment: I tried the script but it seems that the terminal does not recognize the command channel.send(announcement);